# Tags: Vatican or Vatican-City?

Tags: discussion

There is a tag called "[Vatican City](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vatican-city)" for questions related to the micro state in the middle of Rome. Although Vatican-City is a more official designation, most people refer to it as Vatican. Hence I would find it preferable to have a Vatican tag. The Vatican-City tag could then be redirected to the more simple Vatican tag.

Comment: weird, I've never referred to it as Vatican.  But a google search seems to agree with you.  @Ankur has made a synonym though, so that should suit everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Vatican' is now a synonym of Vatican City.

Comment: By the time you type in "Vatican" the tag-auto-completion already gives you "vatican-city" so it was virtually already a synonym. Can't hurt though (-:

Answer (score 1):

They're just tags. I don't find it important at all as long as the tag isn't confusing.

It's the tag's wiki that has the job to clarify what the tag is for, not its name.

However I find that for me "Vatican" or "the Vatican" is most often as a [metonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-referring-to-an-organization-by-its-city-rather-than-by-its) to refer to the Catholic church.

"Vatican-city" does not have this connotation since it refers just to the place with no overtones.